# Email confirmations are not stored Django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, email-confirmation

I am using Django allauth with django-rest-auth. I implemented authentication with email confirmation. But now I realize that it does not work exactly as it should since I don't have stored send email confirmation in my DB (can't see them in admin). Email confirmation is being send as it should and it works perfect, just I can't see them in db. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [version 0.26](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#id10):

> By default, email confirmations are no longer stored in the database. Instead, the email confirmation mail contains an HMAC based key identifying the email address to confirm.

That is, instead of generating a random key and storing it for later lookup, allauth generates a key from account information that it can then re-generate and verify during the confirmation process.